# Infinite primes of the form 3n+2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Without recourse to Dirichlet's theorem, of course.
We're going to go over the problems in class but I'd prefer to know the answer today.

Let $S = \{3n+2 \in \mathbb P: n \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}\}$

edit:

The original question is "the set of all primes of the form $3n + 2$, but I was only considering odd primes because of a reason I don't remember anymore.

How can I show $S$ is infinite? I start by assuming it's finite.

I've tried:

Assuming that the product $(3n_1+2)(3n_2+2)...(3n_m+2)$ is of the form "something" so I can show the product contains a prime factor not in the finite list of primes, which would be a contradiction, but came up with no useful "something".

I tried showing that the product would not be square-free, but couldn't show that.

I tried showing the product or sum was both even and odd, but couldn't show that.

What else should I try? Or was one of the above methods correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general strategy is to find a (large) number $n$ that is relatively prime to each of the existing list of such primes, and is also congruent to 2 modulo 3.  The prime factorization of $n$ cannot consist only of primes congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, since the product of any number of such is still $1$ modulo $3$.  Hence there must be some prime factor of $n$ that is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, which must be not on our list by the construction of $n$.

Now, how to construct such an $n$?  Suppose the finite list is $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k\}$.  If $k$ is even, then take $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k+1$.  If $k$ is odd, then take $n=(p_1p_2\cdots p_k)p_k+1$.

Comment: ... or use $(p_1p_2\cdots p_k)^2+1$ regardless

Comment: It makes sense now that you say it, but how did you think of what $n$ to use?

Comment: This is a standard trick, I read it in a book.

Comment: @vadim123 : $\:$ Your strategy will only work _after_ checking that there is at least one such prime. $\hspace{.73 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer, not so -- the empty product is defined as $1$, so my definition gives $n=2$, and the proof works fine.

Comment: Also checking that 2 is a prime of the form $3n+2$ isn't exactly difficult

Comment: @vadim123 how to choose if $k$ should be even or odd? I understand the procedure, only this step is confusing

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ in your question is even, the number can't be a prime. So it suffices to prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $6n-1$.

Assume there are only finitely many of them let $n_1\ldots,n_k$ be their representants. Then
$$6\bigl((6n_1-1)(6n_2-1)\ldots(6n_k-1)\bigr)-1$$
is a number of the form $6n-1$ which is not divisible by $2,3,$ and any of the primes of the form $6n-1$.

But all primes are either $2$, $3$, or of the form $6n\pm1$, so the number must be a product of primes of the form $6n+1$, but that's impossible because product of such numbers has again the form $6n+1$.

Comment: @vadim123 I was just about to comment the same, but $2\notin S$ (see definition), and then the number is odd

Comment: edited my question to clarify

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you're right, this approach can be patched.

Comment: @vadim123 I rewrote it to be more natural and easy to see.

Comment: Interesting, how did you know the "all primes are either..." part?

Comment: @GFauxPas Because $6k{+}2 = 2(3k{+}1)$, $6k{+}3 = 3(2k{+}1)$ and $6k{+}4=2(3k{+}2)$, so only $6k{+}1$ and $6k{+}5=6(k{+}1)-1$ remain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Assume there are only $m$ such primes. Consider
$$P=(3n_1+2)(3n_2+2)...(3n_m+2) = (-1)^m \mod 3$$

Now if $2|m, P+2 = -1\mod 3$.

If $2\nmid m$ then $P=1\mod 3$.